# what relation should I use to get 1 soccer player to view all his matches?

Tags: database, relationship, erd, greendao

As a soccer player I want to view all the matches I played, but a match shouldn't keep track of which player played that match.

Like the title says, what database-relation should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a player table and a match table, I'd hold a third table to map the relationship between the two. This table will hold the player id (a foreign key to the player table), the match id (a foreign key to the match table) and the combination of the two would be its primary key. It could also hold some additional information like when the player came on and when we went off (e.g., via red card or via substitution).

```
CREATE TABLE player (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other player details
);

CREATE TABLE match (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other match details
);

CREATE TABLE player_matches (
    player_id INT,
    match_id INT,
    minute_on INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    minute_off INT,
    CONSTRAINT player_matches_pk PRIMARY KEY (player_id, match_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_player FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES player(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_match FOREIGN KEY (match_id) REFERENCES match(id)
);
```